# Boothby's exercise $I.3.1$ on showing that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

First time here, so sorry for the rookie mistakes. I'm a $4^{th}$ year physics student taking Riemannian Geometry so my background on the subject is very small.

I'm trying to solve Boothby's exercise $I.3.1$ on showing that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not a manifold. The subset is $X = A_{+} \cup A_{-} \cup B$ with

$A_{+} = \{(x,y): x \geq 0, y=+1 \}$

$A_{-} = \{(x,y): x \geq 0, y=-1 \}$

$B = \{(x,y): x < 0, y=0 \}$

EDIT sugested by Travis: Boothby indeed tells the reader how to define a topology. So, what Boothby does is to use the subspace topology on $A_{+}-\{(0,1)\}$, $A_{-}-\{(0,-1)\}$ and B, then for $\epsilon>0$ he lets $N_{\epsilon}^{\pm} = \{(x,\pm 1): 0 \leq x < \epsilon\} \cup \{(x,0): −\epsilon \leq x<0\}$, finally he uses this as a basis of neighborhoods of $(0,1)$ and $(0,−1)$, respectively for $+$ and for $−$.

I've shown that the space X is locally Euclidean but I don't know what to do from here. Obviously it must have something to do with the remaining conditions for a manifold, but I'm unfamiliarized with the concepts of Hausdorff spaces and the second axiom of numerability.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a manifold but a manifold with boundary. In particular, there is no neighborhood of $(0, 1)$ which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (all connected neighborhoods of $(0, 1)$ are half-open intervals $[0, a) \times \{+1\}$). Is it possible that the question is asking about the quotient of $X$ as indicated modulo the identification of the three points in $X$ on the $y$-axis?

Comment: Hey Travis, I think I understand your point. The question is simply to "Show that the space X is locally Euclidean but is not a manifold.".

Comment: Boothby indeed tells the reader how to define a topology (and now that I think about it, I believe this is what I need to use to show that either X is not Hausdorff or that it is not second countable). So, what Boothby does is to use the subspace topology on $A_{+} - \{(0,1)\}$, $A_{-} - \{(0,-1)\}$ and B, then for $\epsilon>0$ he lets $N_{\epsilon}^{\pm} = \{ (x,\pm 1): 0 \leq x < \epsilon\} \cup \{ (x,0): -\epsilon \leq x < 0\}$, finally he uses this as a basis of neighborhoods of $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$, respectively for $+$ and for $-$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. This is not the same as the topology I'd suggested, which would have yielded a Hausdorff and second countable but not locally Euclidean space. I'll write up an answer now. In the meantime you might like to include the description of the topology in your question, since, as we've seen, the topology is an essential ingredient here, and the three different topologies we've discussed yield spaces with different properties.

Comment: Indeed I should, as you can see physicists doing mathematics... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the so-called *[branching line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold)* (counter)example, which is related to a perhaps better-known example known as the *line with two origins*.

To show that a space $X$ is not Hausdorff, it suffices to pick two points $x, y$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$, $U \cap V \neq 0$. We know that away from the points on the $y$-axis the topology looks like the usual (subspace) topology, which *is* Hausdorff, which suggests the problem points should be on the $y$-axis, and there are only two of these, namely $(0, \pm 1)$, and we know what the neighborhoods of these spaces are.

Once you've sorted this problem, you might like to try to prove that another space is not a manifold, namely, the union of three distinct rays (in, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$) with a common vertex, which is what I initially thought your problem might have referred to.